# WPF XAML DataGrid populating sub DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and XAML. Sorry if this seems simple, but I have a set of classes:

```
Public class Master()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

Public class Student()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to display them in a datagrid, so I have created and configured a datagrid control on my page.

I have then bound my classes above using:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = result.Master.ToList();
```

This provides me with the list, but what I am trying to do is also display the student collection against each master row. At the moment all I get is (Collection) populated in the student record of the datagrid.

Comment: You could just have 2 datagrids side by side, when you select one row `Master` it populates the second datagrid `Student`

Comment: How would that be done Keyur? As I said, I am new to this WPF/XAML programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move from comments to an answer:

I assume you know how to make another datagrid, since you already have 1 with correct bindings. Just copy paste another one and move it to one side.

For this other datagrid, let's call it dataGrid2.

On the first datagrid: add this to your xaml:

`SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged"`

and in code behind:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selected = dataGrid.SelectedItem as Master;
    dataGrid2.ItemsSource = selected.Students.ToList();
}
```

I haven't included everything, such as error checking and empty selection handling, etc. So you will need to implement it.